# Algebraic equation translation

Tags: linear-algebra

One scoop of ice cream has 5mg of cholesterol less than the amount of cholesterol in one hamburger.

Together, they have 37mg of cholesterol.

How much cholesterol is in each food?

Answer (score 1):

Set $I$ to be the amount of cholesterol in the scoop of ice cream, $H$ the amount in the hamburger.

Then, translating the assumptions:
$$
I=H-5\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad I+H=37.
$$

I think you can take it from here.